# Beginner Java: How do I write a constructor to call methods?

Tags: java, methods, constructor, call

I am trying to figure out how to write a constructor that calls methods. I have been given the following instructions for a Java project. The emboldened ones are relevant to this step. Step 3 I have completed, but I can't confirm if I completed it correctly. The code for Step 3 is the second Date constructor within the Date class.

1. Uncomment line 1 from DateTest (don’t forget to delete the “Line 1.” part) and build and run the project.  What is the output?  Why is this the output?
2. Create a default constructor for Date which sets the date to 1/1/2000.  Build and run the project.  What is the output?
3. **Create a constructor that has three int parameters for the month, day, and year and sets the values of these instance variables to the values passed in.  Uncomment lines 2 and 3.  Build and run the project.  What is the output?**
4. **Rewrite the constructor from question 3 so that it calls setMonth(), setDay(), and setYear().  Build and run the project.  What is the output?**
5. **Write a set() method that has three parameters for the month, day, and year.  Uncomment lines 4 and 5.  Build and run the project.  What is the output?**
6. Rewrite the constructor from question 3 so that it calls set ().  Build and run the project.  What is the output?

Below is the code for Date class and DateTest class.

```
package datetest;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Date
{
public Date() {
    month = 1;
    day = 1;
    year = 2000;
}
public Date(int m, int d, int y) {
    month = m;
    day = d;
    year = y;
}
private int month;
private int day;
private int year; //a four digit number.


public void setYear(int newYear)
{
   year = newYear;
}
public void setMonth(int newMonth)
{
    if ((newMonth <= 0) || (newMonth > 12))
    {
        month=newMonth;
    }
    else
        month = newMonth;
}

public void setDay(int newDay)
{
    if ((newDay <= 0) || (newDay > 31))
    {
        day=1;
    }
    else
        day = newDay;
}

public int getMonth( )
{
    return month;
}


public int getDay( )
{
    return day;
}

public int getYear( )
{
    return year;
}

public void printDate( )
{
    System.out.print(getMonth() + "/" + getDay() + "/" + getYear());
}


public void readInput( )
{
    boolean tryAgain = true;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter month, day, and year.");
    System.out.println("Do not use a comma.");
    month = keyboard.nextInt( );
    day = keyboard.nextInt( );
    year = keyboard.nextInt( );
}

}
```

This is the DateTest class.

```
package datetest;


public class DateTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Date today = new Date();

        System.out.println("Today’s date is " + today.getMonth() + "/" + today.getDay() + "/" + today.getYear());
        //Line 2. today = new Date(55, 55, 2011);
        //Line 3. System.out.println("Today’s date is " + today.getMonth() + "/" + today.getDay() + "/" + today.getYear());
        //Line 4. today.set(10, 5, 2011);
        //Line 5. System.out.println("Today’s date is " + today.getMonth() + "/" + today.getDay() + "/" + today.getYear());

 }
}
```

I have attempted to write the code to call the methods in step 4. Would the following code be the correct way to write a constructor to call methods?

```
   public Date (int m, int d, int y) {
   this.setMonth(month);
   this.setDay(day);
   this.setYear(year);
}
```

Comment: You should mention in your post that this is a homework project.

Comment: @Brian:  I doubt that matters much.

Comment: As far as this goes, it seems that you've created the constructor correctly.  What would make you think that you haven't?  Did you get an exception?  Did the code not compile?

Comment: It would be "correct" after some changes.. start with the *actual error* and solve it. First the problem needs to be *identified*. Some compilers/IDEs (eclipse?) ought to give a useful warning about "unused variables"; but the unfortunate accidental use of using the *member* variables is *set their own setter* is not an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would the following code be the correct way to write a constructor to call methods?

```
public Date (int m, int d, int y) {
   this.setMonth(month);
   this.setDay(day);
   this.setYear(year);
}
```

Yes, if you used your `m`, `d`, and `y` arguments instead of `month`, `day`, and `year`:

```
public Date (int m, int d, int y) {
   this.setMonth(m);
   this.setDay(d);
   this.setYear(y);
}
```

With your code, you're actually just setting the instance members (`month` and so on) to their existing values (because `month` in the constructor is automatically resolved to the instance data member `month` using an implied `this.`). So I'm guessing when you tried it, you ended up with zeroes and didn't understand why. (`int` members are auto-initialized to zero before the code in the constructor runs.)

Comment: Yes, I believe the date returned 0/1/0. I had to run to the bathroom but I'm about to try this, thank you.